# Any idea how to change encoding for subtitles?

Tags: videos, video-player

thanks for great OS system!

Any idea how to change encoding of subtitles in default video app?

Comment: Already reported here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/audience/+bug/1360085

Comment: I have the same problem. Please someone help me?? I don't want install VLC or etc.

Comment: +1 I really like the default Videos app and would like to see some improvements and settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/):

```
file -> reopen with encoding -> {current_encoding}
```

then

```
file -> save with encoding -> {new_encoding}
```

Comment: Yea.. but this is.... sad to do it everytime when I want to watch something..